# Data Validation range from different spreadsheets

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, dropdown, importrange

I have in my main spreadsheet a dropdown with data validation of a range from another tab in the same spreadsheet with data imported from another spreadsheet or with IMPORTRANGE function or imported with a script.

In both cases the main spreadsheet is very slow cause I have a lot of tab with data imported with both methods.

There is a way to do the data validation of the dropdown in the main sheet taking the data I need **directly** from the other spreadsheets without import them previously in the main spreadsheet with the IMPORTRANGE function or with a script?

I have tried to write a draft script but not works:

```
function externalSheetDataValidation() {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var dataValidationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxx");
    var sheet = dataValidationSheet.getSheets()[0];
    var range  = sheet.getRange("B2:B5000");
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInRange(range, true)
        .setAllowInvalid(false)
        .build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);  
    Logger.log(dataValidationSheet.getName());
}
```

Comment: Ans so how can I solve for you in order to increase the speed of the main spreadsheet?

Comment: And so for you there in another solution to speed up the main  spreadsheet?

Comment: I use datavalidation cause in the main tab of the main sheet I need of all the data from another sheet togheter to other data of the main sheet.

Comment: Datavalidation is located in col A with a VLookup from the tab with the importrage. Then togheter with other data inserted in the following columns, I must to generate some documents, and so I need of this combination of data.

Comment: Sure, but if you read my question, the problem is the speed. I have a lot of import in the main sheet and so I would to find an alternative.

Comment: How about using a custom dialog you can get it's data from anything you want you could even store it in cache.

Comment: Can you show me the process?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing?

Comment: This question is refered to another my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707848/generate-google-doc-from-different-spreadsheets but the scope is the same. I have a main spreadsheet with different dropdown in various columns that with VLookup function, call the data from some tabs with the Importrange functions or script. But it is all very slow.

Comment: Never mind. I've read that before and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: In any case, I have insert both GS and HTML in a spreadsheet. Now how can I proceed?

Comment: Have you considered using `requireValueInList` instead? Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet/s you're working on?

Comment: Consider I have 6 tab with 20000 rows and 40 columns each one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uAZcm9P4XR9h58nyUXtxZxSLN5GY_RHgyRRcP_Phycg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, and this huge quantity of cells is the reason why this gets slow. But this way you could avoid importing the data to another sheet. What I would do in your case is create an `onEdit` trigger on your source spreadsheet which would update the data validation when the source range is edited. What do you think of that?

Comment: @lamblichus Yes. I have this script on the main sheet that import the data from the other sheets. And so how could I proceed? function importSheetA() { var values1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx'). getSheetByName('Tirocini Formativi').getRange('A1:D3000').getValues(); SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Import-Tirocini-Fase1'). getRange(1,1,values1.length,values1[0].length).setValues(values1); }

Comment: Hi, was your issue solved?

Comment: Hi, can I share the sheet with you?

Comment: Isn't it the one you already shared? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uAZcm9P4XR9h58nyUXtxZxSLN5GY_RHgyRRcP_Phycg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: btw, can you quote me in order to make sure I receive your message? Like @Iamblichus

Answer (score 1):

- You want to populate a dropdown based on the values of a range from a different spreadsheet.
- You are currently importing those values to a sheet in your spreadsheet in order to use them via `requireValueInRange`.
- You would like to skip the import process.

If that's the case, you can just do the following:

- Create a function that `returns` a simple array with the values from the source range:

```js
function importSheetA() { 
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
                       .getSheetByName('xxxxx')
                       .getRange('xxxxx')
                       .getValues()
                       .flat(); // This ensures a simple array is returned
}
```

- Populate the dropdowns with `requireValueInList` instead of `requireValueInRange`, using the values returned by `importSheetA`:

```js
function populateDropdown() {
  var values = importSheetA();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(values, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .build();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

#### Note:

- You could update the populated options when the source range is edited if you [install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) an `onEdit` trigger, and you could also specify what range of cells should be populated with dropdowns without them being necessarily selected, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

#### Update:

If your data has more than 500 items, `value in list` criteria is not an option. Your only other option would be to use `List from a range` instead, but as you said, this would require the source range to be on the same spreadsheet as the dropdown, which you wanted to avoid.

As a workaround, I'd suggest you to programmatically copy the data to a hidden sheet in the target spreadsheet, and use the data in this hidden sheet as your source range when creating the dropdown. For example, this:

```
function copyRange() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var rangeNotation = "B2:B5000"; // Change according to your preferences
  var sourceData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(xxxxx)
                       .getSheetByName(xxxxx)
                       .getRange(rangeNotation)
                       .getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hiddenSheetName = "Hidden source data"; // Change according to your preferences
  var hiddenSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName(hiddenSheetName);
  if (!hiddenSheet) hiddenSheet = targetSS.insertSheet(hiddenSheetName);
  var sourceRange = hiddenSheet.getRange(rangeNotation);
  sourceRange.setValues(sourceData);
  hiddenSheet.hideSheet();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [requireValueInList(values, showDropdown)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues,-showdropdown)

Comment: I have tested your script, it works, but the dropdown is limited to 500 values and I need to populate the entire column C with the dropdown. How to do that?

Comment: @Popoff Unfortunately, if you want more than 500 values, you have to use `ValueInRange`. I updated my answer with a workaround to make this the less painful possible. Let me know if that's appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cached Dropdown Dialog

GS:

```
function getSelectOptions(){
  const cs=CacheService.getScriptCache();
  const v=JSON.parse(cs.get('cached'));
  if(v){return v;}
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  cs.put('cached', JSON.stringify(vA), 300)
  return vA;
}

function showMyselectionDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'), 'Selections');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
    google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(vA) {
    updateSelect(vA);
  })
  .getSelectOptions();

function updateSelect(vA,id){//the id allows me to use it for other elements
  var id=id || 'sel1';
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
  </script>
  <body>
     <select id='sel1'></select>
  </body>
</html>
```